# ExpanderView assigning DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've got a StackPanel which I need to fill in with **ExpanderViews** based on my data.
I am creating the ExpanderViews in *code-behind* and assigning to it, the **DataTemplate** present in the XAML.

The problem is, I am able to create the ExpanderView programmatically, but the DataTemplate approach doesn't work. All I can see is the "Expander Header" which doesn't show the items after click.

However, I can add Items manually to the ExpanderView and it shows the Items.

Please help!

C# Code:

```
ExpanderView expandOne = new ExpanderView()
    {
        Width = 400,
        Margin = new Thickness(2),
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Expander = new Border()
                    {
                        Width = 400,
                        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown),
                        Child = new TextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = "Expander Header",
                            FontSize = 34,
                            Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                            Margin = new Thickness(40, 5, 5, 5),
                        },
                    },
    };

// Assign DataTemplate
DataTemplate temp = (DataTemplate)FindName("ItemTemplateName");
expandOne.ItemTemplate = temp;

// add ExpanderView to StackPanel
this.MyStackPanel.Children.Add(expandOne);
```

XAML Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateKey" x:Name="ItemTemplateName">
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ItemListBox">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <TextBlock Text="Filter Content 1" Foreground="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Filter Content 2" Foreground="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Filter Content 3" Foreground="Black"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for an answer, I solved this by using the solution mentioned in

[DataBinding to WP8 Toolkit ExpanderView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138584/databinding-to-wp8-toolkit-expanderview)